# How can I translate "Author Note" in apa6 into german?

Tags: babel, apa6, german

I want to create a german paper in APA 6 format. Using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

works, but the headline for the authors note on the title page remains untranslated. How can I fix this?

My document is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\title{Der Titel}
\shorttitle{Der Kurztitel}
\author{Hans Peter}
\affiliation{Universität}
\note{19.09.2016}
\authornote{Man erreicht den Autor unter}
\abstract{mein Abstract}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Text hier
\end{document}
```

I refer to this headline here:

[image: my titlepage]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The English terms are happily defined using macros `\rheadname` et al.
Since these macros are also defined in `\begin{document}`, the redefinitions are done at the end of the preamble using `\AtBeginDocument`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\title{Der Titel}
\shorttitle{Der Kurztitel}
\author{Hans Peter}
\affiliation{Universität}
\note{19.09.2016}
\authornote{Man erreicht den Autor unter}
\abstract{mein Abstract}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand*{\rheadname}{Laufende Kopfzeile}%
  \renewcommand*{\acksname}{Autorhinweis}%
  \renewcommand*{\keywordname}{Schl\"usselw\"orter}%
  \renewcommand*{\notesname}{Fu\ss noten}%
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Text hier
\end{document}
```